# Is there a switch case in Javafx 1.2?

Tags: switch-statement, javafx

Is there a switch case in Javafx 1.2?

Comment: A simple Google works, too: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5407268

Comment: I wasn't able to find that. Thanks S.Lott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas... no switch, case or whatsoever.

Here's a rather complete overview... http://jarfiller.com/reference/javafxscript/